# Oracle 12c : Restrict a specific schema user on active node (in active-passive setup)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Our DBA is in the process of setting up read-only mode (on passive node) in an active-passive DB setup. This would enable us to setup RO schema to connect to passive node (for report querying). DBA says it is not technically possible to disable/restrict RO schema getting connect/access active node. We (App team) would wanted to prevent this. Please suggest a solution/workaround.

DB: Oracle 12c.

Comment: Oracle uses roles and grants to restrict or grant access to schemas. The documentation is here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm

Comment: Can you please more specific? The restriction to schema/user account needs to be enforced only for active node. Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to be more specific without a specific question.  The passive/active terminology you use is not used by Oracle.  Please explain more about what you want to do, how you want to authorize and authenticate and what reporting solution you intend to use

Comment: The answer will depend on the specific technology being used.  If your "passive node" is a logical standby that is part of a DataGuard environment, the answer is very different than if you have a reporting database being maintained by Streams or GoldenGate.  If we assume that the DBA is implying that whatever architecture you are using is one that shares privileges across the instances, there is a very good chance that an appropriate login trigger would work assuming your goal is to prevent inadvertent connections rather than dedicated attacks.

Comment: Yes, the technology is a standby node and is part of DataGuard setup. Would you mind explain more on login trigger please? Thanks.